# Does heat kernel factorize on product spaces?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry

I have a doubt regarding whether the trace of the vector heat kernel on a product space factorizes into the corresponding heat kernel traces on each manifold in the product space. I know this holds for the spin-0 as well as spin-1/2 cases, but I am not sure about the spin-1 case. Can somebody please help me out in this regard?